# Date is not updated in DatePicker component after calling onChange method when testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, react-datepicker

I have started writing unit-tests recently and I faced with an issue. So, I use `react-datepicker` and `material-ui` packages in my little project.

Here is my `DatePickerItem` component below:

```
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid/Grid";
import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from "react-datepicker";
import React from "react";
import { subDays } from "date-fns";
import ru from "date-fns/locale/ru";

registerLocale("ru", ru);

type Props = {
  selectedDate: Date;
  setDate: (date: Date) => void;
};

const DEMO_LIFE_TIME = 7;

export const DatePickerItem: React.FC<Props> = ({ setDate, selectedDate }) => {
  const rangeStartDate = subDays(new Date(), DEMO_LIFE_TIME);
  const rangeEndDate = new Date();

  return (
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <DatePicker
        locale="ru"
        selected={selectedDate}
        minDate={rangeStartDate}
        maxDate={rangeEndDate}
        showTimeSelect
        timeFormat="HH:mm"
        timeIntervals={1}
        dateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
        onChange={(date: Date) => setDate(date)}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

This component is used to let a user select a date.
I created the following test for this component:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from "enzyme";
import { subDays } from "date-fns";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid/Grid";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import { DatePickerItem } from "../DatePickerItem";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const DEMO_LIFE_TIME = 7;

describe("Datepicker component", () => {
  let component: ShallowWrapper;

  const createComponent = (props = {}) => {
    const selectedDate = new Date();
    const setDate = jest.fn();

    return shallow(
      <DatePickerItem
        setDate={setDate}
        selectedDate={selectedDate}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  };

  afterEach(() => {
    component.unmount();
  });

  it("should render changed startDate", () => {
    const event = {
      target: {
        value: subDays(new Date(), DEMO_LIFE_TIME - 4)
      }
    };
    const setDateMock = jest.fn();
    component = createComponent({
      setDate: setDateMock
    });
    const gridContainer = component.find(Grid);
    const datePickers = gridContainer.find(DatePicker);

    const firstDatePicker = datePickers.at(0);

    firstDatePicker.simulate("change", event);

    expect(setDateMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(firstDatePicker.props().minDate).toEqual(event.target.value);
  });
});
```

[image]
I expect that the value of the `minDate` property will be changed after calling `onChange` method but unfortunately my test doesn't work correctly.

I would like to find out the reason why my test doesn't work correctly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any updates on this?